# Python Incorrect integer value: '(2L,)' for column 'id' at row 1

Tags: python, mysql

i use Python and I get an "Incorrect integer value: '(2L,)' for column 'id' at row 1"

Thats it what i do:

```
for user in users:
            userID = self.selectQuery("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user;")
            self.changeQuery("INSERT INTO user VALUES ('" + str(userID[0]) + "', '" + str(user) + "','','');")

def changeQuery (self, query):

    connection = MySQLdb.connect(self.mysql_host, self.mysql_user, self.mysql_password, self.mysql_db)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute (query)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Come on. Is this really all the information you think we need?

Comment: I edited the thread! :) better?

Comment: You don't think it would be easier to answer with, say, the complete error output?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `str()` and string concatenation when you can use SQL parameters instead; also, your `userID` variable contains a list of tuples, not a list of integers; your function must be returning all results as rows. The following would work if you had a database cursor reference:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user VALUES (%s, %s,'','');", (userID[0][0], user))
```

Using SQL parameters has the added advantage that the database adapter will apply the correct quoting to whatever values you are passing in. Strings will be quoted, integers not, for example, and most importantly, dangerous SQL injection attempts are thwarted.

The exact syntax for specifying SQL parameters depends on your database adapter. I used `%s` style positional parameters (as you used the [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) tag), but depending on the database adapter, any of the following can be supported:

- `?` positional parameters
- `%s` positional parameters (used my MySQLdb, for example)
- `:name` named parameters
- `%(name)s` named parameters

Check your database adapter documentation for the exact variants that are supported.

What happened in your case is that `userID[0]` is a *tuple* containing a python long integer, whose string representation includes an `L`. Your database would not have accepted your query even if it didn't, as you were assuming all input values were strings anyway, and you were putting quotes around the value regardless. Querying for a string `"0"` where an integer is expected won't work.

To extrapolate this to your expanded function:

```
def changeQuery(self, query, parameters=()):    
    connection = MySQLdb.connect(self.mysql_host, self.mysql_user, self.mysql_password, self.mysql_db)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, parameters)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

and call with:

```
self.changeQuery("INSERT INTO user VALUES (%s, %s,'','');", (userID[0][0], user))
```

Comment: now i get TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: @Furtano: further updated; your `userID` variable is most likely a list of tuples.